# Is there a fast way to figure out the source of all dependencies in my node.js / npm project?

Tags: node.js, dependencies, npm

`npm` is capable of installing dependencies from the official `npm` registry, git urls, HTTP urls, and other sources. Is there a fast way to recursively determine where all of the dependencies in my project came from?

Basically I need to make sure that all of my dependencies are coming form the same place. One thing I've thought of is recursively reading all `package.json` files and making sure that all dependencies are a valid `semver` number. Does NPM have any tools for this built in? Are there any quick shell tricks I can use rather than writing a node script to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm` puts url of downloaded package in _resolved field. So you can cat all packages.json and grep this field. Example of shell trick:

```
find node_modules -name "package.json" | xargs cat | grep "_resolved"
```

If you want to see which packages are not from npmjs, then

```
find node_modules -name "package.json" | xargs cat | grep "_resolved" | grep -v npmjs.org
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Actually, there appears to be a small problem. Not all package.json files have a "_resolved" field. It looks like there was an [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm-www/issues/351) opened but nothing ever came of it.